# Jsch-0.1.50.jar souce code

Tags: java, security, remote-access, jsch

plesse tell me that from where i can get Jsch-0.1.50 source code zip file. I need to look into the source code or tell me how to establish connection by using key which is stored in a file to the linux server.

Comment: The source is in the main jar itself...

Answer (score 0):

jsch-0.1.50.zip file contains src folder which contains all java files. we can create jar file of that source by using command line jar utility.